# R Shiny - How do I let the user set the seed?

Tags: r, shiny

I was instructed that for my R Shiny web application, I need to let the user set the seed for the following computations. However, I keep on getting an error.

Although the codebase for the exact usecase is too large, I have simplified the problem (and it doesn't work in the simple case as well.) See the example below:

```
library(shiny)

# Function that uses a randomizer ##########

random_test_function = function(){
  x = rnorm(3)
  y = rgamma(3, shape = 1)
  return(x + y)
}

# Define UI ################################
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(inputId = "chosen_seed",
                   label = "Please select a seed for rnorm.",
                   value = 1),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("test_normal")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ######################
server <- function(input, output) {
  global_seed = reactive(input$chosen_seed)
  #set.seed(1) # This works!
  set.seed(global_seed()) # This does not work!
  
  # Also tried the repeatable function - but it doesn't work either!
  #repeatable_test_function = repeatable(random_test_function(), seed = as.numeric(global_seed()))
  #repeatable_test_function = repeatable(random_test_function(), seed = 1) # This works!
  
  output$test_normal = renderPrint({
    random_test_function()
    #repeatable_test_function()
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This will provide the following error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
• You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.
```

I also read about the [repeatable function](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.13.0/repeatable.html) and tried to use it (see what's commented out), but it also doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this, or is it impossible?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try it in a reactive context `observe(set.seed(global_seed()))`

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't seem to change depending on the user's input (which was my goal.)

Comment: Sorry. Missed something else. Your test is not reactive either. Adding solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(shiny)

# Function that uses a randomizer ##########

# simplified for testing
random_test_function = function(){
    runif(1)
}

# Define UI ################################
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(inputId = "chosen_seed",
                   label = "Please select a seed for rnorm.",
                   value = 1),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("test_normal")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ######################
server <- function(input, output) {
  global_seed = reactive(input$chosen_seed)
  #set.seed(1) # This works!

  # Also tried the repeatable function - but it doesn't work either!
  #repeatable_test_function = repeatable(random_test_function(), seed = as.numeric(global_seed()))
  #repeatable_test_function = repeatable(random_test_function(), seed = 1) # This works!
  
  output$test_normal = renderPrint({
    # the new global seed will trigger the function
    set.seed(global_seed())
    random_test_function()
    #repeatable_test_function()
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

@SmokeyShakers was correct. The reason your ouptut isn't changing is because there are no dependencies in your `renderPrint({...})` expression.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  global_seed = reactive(input$chosen_seed)
  
  # reactives can only be in observers or other reactives.
  # setting priority to 5 helps set seed before `renderPrint` is executed
  observe({
    set.seed(global_seed()) 
  }, priority = 5)



  output$test_normal = renderPrint({
    # adding `input$chosen_seed` causes this expression to be called
    # each time the value does
    input$chosen_seed
    random_test_function()
    #repeatable_test_function()
  })
}
```